How to batch process PDF to store into Chroma vector store
I have 3 folders, each containing PDFs categorized based on specific criteria in their names. I want to use PDFLoader to load these PDFs and store them in a Chroma vector store. Here is how my code to load the PDFs and create a Chroma collection looks like:
pdf_folder_path = "/content"
    documents = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(pdf_folder_path):
      for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdf_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_path)
            documents.extend(loader.load())
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=10)
    chunked_documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    client = chromadb.Client()
    if client.list_collections():
        law_collection = client.create_collection("law_collection")
    else:
    vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
        documents=chunked_documents,
        embedding=OllamaEmbeddings(model="nomic-embed-text", show_progress=True),
        persist_directory="/content/db"
    )
]

Since I have thousands of PDF adding up from the three folders this code is not very time effective. If I have already loaded all the PDFs from folder one and added them to the collection, can I add documents from folder two and update the collection?
I ran the code as is and set the pdf_folder_path to the root directory, but the code took too long to run and I want to know if there are any way to save time by processing the PDFs in batches.
